# How control access to specific folder using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using a .htaccess file in Apache for controlling access to a folder. I would like to allow access to a specific folder. How can I do it?

```
AuthName "Admin page protected"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/var/www/demo/.htpasswd"
require user admin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/folder/ NO_AUTH

AuthName "Admin page protected"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/var/www/demo/.htpasswd"
require user admin
Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=NO_AUTH
```

---

**Alternative solution:**

Create a file called `version/.htaccess` and place these lines:

```
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
```

Comment: i have inside demo : .htaccess , .htpasswd , version/ , data/.                        i would like to allow access to public for to the content of the folder version and control it for the others files and folders.

Comment: thanks it works , with an absolute url for the folder.